# Battery level is never updated

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, batterylevel

I want to display the current watch battery level in my watch face. While the value is determined exactly once and then displayed in my watch face correctly, that value is then never updated. The only way to get a new value displayed is either reinstalling the APK through Android Studio or selecting another watch face first.

I think I followed the tutorial code closely. Here's the relevant parts of my `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine` class:

```
inner class Engine : CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine() {
    private lateinit var batteryBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
    private lateinit var batteryStatus: Intent
    private var watchBatteryLevel: Int = -1

    override fun onCreate(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(holder)
        setWatchFaceStyle(WatchFaceStyle.Builder(this@MyWatchFaceService)
                .setAcceptsTapEvents(true)
                .build())
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
        batteryBroadcastReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                watchBatteryLevel = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        batteryStatus = registerReceiver(batteryBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME)
        unregisterReceiver(batteryBroadcastReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas, bounds: Rect) {
        val batteryText = String.format("%d %%", watchBatteryLevel)
        canvas.drawText(batteryText, width * 0.5f, width * 0.15f, mBatteryPaint)
    }
}
```

Comment: So ... do you know if your onReceive method is being called?

Comment: It's the only place where `watchBatteryLevel` is set, so it must be called at least once. Then probably never, or it gets an outdated level value. I don't know that. Debugging doesn't work. Edit: I've logged it and it always returns the old value. API bug?

Comment: Do you know that it is being called **more than once**?  (Use logging ...)

Comment: Yes, every ~10 seconds, always the same value returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery level is taken from `batteryStatus` which is only set once. Take it from the `intent` parameter of `onReceive` instead.